# Elegant way to remove fields from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I had to remove some fields from a dictionary, the keys for those fields are on a list. So I wrote this function:

```
def delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del, lst_keys):
    """
    Delete the keys present in lst_keys from the dictionary.
    Loops recursively over nested dictionaries.
    """
    dict_foo = dict_del.copy()  #Used as iterator to avoid the 'DictionaryHasChanged' error
    for field in dict_foo.keys():
        if field in lst_keys:
            del dict_del[field]
        if type(dict_foo[field]) == dict:
            delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del[field], lst_keys)
    return dict_del
```

This code works, but it's not very elegant and I'm sure that there is a better solution.

Comment: I think it's not bad code; you've got the important bit which is recursing over nested dictionaries. You should probably check `isinstance( spam, collections.MutableMapping )` to be more polymorphic.

Comment: I don't like recursion.  How can your remove items from nested dictionaries without recursion?

Comment: I am bridging my knowledge betweet R and Python and I gotta say R and purrr package with map functions make working with lists/jsons etc a lot easier than I have found in python so far.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First of, I think your code is working and not *inelegant*. There's no immediate reason not to use the code you presented.

There are a few things that could be better though:

#### Comparing the type

Your code contains the line:

```
if type(dict_foo[field]) == dict:
```

That can be definitely improved. Generally (see also [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) you should use `isinstance` instead of comparing types:

```
if isinstance(dict_foo[field], dict)
```

However that will also return `True` if `dict_foo[field]` is a subclass of `dict`. If you don't want that, you could also use `is` instead of `==`. That will be marginally (and probably unnoticeable) faster.

If you also want to allow arbitary dict-like objects you could go a step further and test if it's a `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. That will be `True` for `dict` and `dict` subclasses and for all mutable mappings that explicitly implement that interface without subclassing `dict`, for example `UserDict`:

```
>>> from collections import MutableMapping
>>> # from UserDict import UserDict # Python 2.x
>>> from collections import UserDict  # Python 3.x - 3.6
>>> # from collections.abc import MutableMapping # Python 3.7+
>>> isinstance(UserDict(), MutableMapping)
True
>>> isinstance(UserDict(), dict)
False
```

#### Inplace modification and return value

Typically functions either modify a data structure inplace **or** return a new (modified) data structure. Just to mention a few examples: `list.append`, `dict.clear`, `dict.update` all modify the data structure inplace and `return None`. That makes it easier to keep track what a function does. However that's not a hard rule and there are always valid exceptions from this rule. However personally I think a function like this doesn't need to be an exception and I would simply remove the `return dict_del` line and let it implicitly return `None`, but YMMV.

#### Removing the keys from the dictionary

You copied the dictionary to avoid problems when you remove key-value pairs during the iteration. However, as already mentioned by another answer you could just iterate over the keys that should be removed and try to delete them:

```
for key in keys_to_remove:
    try:
        del dict[key]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

That has the additional advantage that you don't need to nest two loops (which *could* be slower, especially if the number of keys that need to be removed is very long).

If you don't like empty `except` clauses you can also use: [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) (requires Python 3.4+):

```
from contextlib import suppress

for key in keys_to_remove:
    with suppress(KeyError):
        del dict[key]
```

#### Variable names

There are a few variables I would rename because they are just not descriptive or even misleading:

- `delete_keys_from_dict` should probably mention the subdict-handling, maybe `delete_keys_from_dict_recursive`.
- `dict_del` sounds like a deleted dict. I tend to prefer names like `dictionary` or `dct` because the function name already describes what is done to the dictionary.
- `lst_keys`, same there. I'd probably use just `keys` there. If you want to be more specific something like `keys_sequence` would make more sense because it accepts any `sequence` (you just have to be able to iterate over it *multiple times*), not just lists.
- `dict_foo`, just no...
- `field` isn't really appropriate either, it's a *key*.

#### Putting it all together:

As I said before I personally would modify the dictionary in-place and **not** return the dictionary again. Because of that I present two solutions, one that modifies it in-place but doesn't return anything and one that creates a new dictionary with the keys removed.

The version that modifies in-place (very much like Ned Batchelders solution):

```
from collections import MutableMapping
from contextlib import suppress

def delete_keys_from_dict(dictionary, keys):
    for key in keys:
        with suppress(KeyError):
            del dictionary[key]
    for value in dictionary.values():
        if isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
            delete_keys_from_dict(value, keys)
```

And the solution that returns a new object:

```
from collections import MutableMapping

def delete_keys_from_dict(dictionary, keys):
    keys_set = set(keys)  # Just an optimization for the "if key in keys" lookup.

    modified_dict = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key not in keys_set:
            if isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
                modified_dict[key] = delete_keys_from_dict(value, keys_set)
            else:
                modified_dict[key] = value  # or copy.deepcopy(value) if a copy is desired for non-dicts.
    return modified_dict
```

However it only makes copies of the dictionaries, the other values are not returned as copy, you could easily wrap these in [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/%C2%B4library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) (I put a comment in the appropriate place of the code) if you want that.

Comment: Wow! this is an impressive answer. I asked this 8 years ago and I learned a lot since then, however I didn't know about `contextlib.suppress` or `MutableMapping`. Thank you very much @MSeifert !

Comment: This is indeed impressive. Learned from it.

It misses recursion into lists, though :-(

@Michael Dorner 's answer below, does not.

Comment: @Mahmoud Hashemi 's answer below is the most modern, except for not doing it's thing 'in place'.

Comment: I'm new to python (4 years of R) but I have a nested JSON file which is a dictionary at first and has lists as you drill down. So when I try your function it probably can't get past the list elements. I am trying to delete some nodes of a json file and I'm stuck. in R I can just do LIST["node1"]["node2"]["node3"] <- NULL

Comment: @BrandonRose I think a new question including some details about your data and how it's structured would be better. There you have also more options to format the text and code.

Comment: For python3.10 + use `from collections.abc import MutableMapping`

Answer (score 22):

```
def delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del, lst_keys):
    for k in lst_keys:
        try:
            del dict_del[k]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    for v in dict_del.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            delete_keys_from_dict(v, lst_keys)

    return dict_del
```

Comment: Sorry but this code doesn't work as expected I try to do:

 print delete_keys_from_dict ({'code': 'sdasda', 'tag.dbmko8e8': {'id':'casas', 'name': 'asdas identyfier'}, 'name': 'collection'}, ["id"])

And delete all the fields from the dictionary :(

Comment: I wasn't returning the dictionary (I've updated the code above).  You were getting "None" printed because the value wasn't being returned.  Since this function doesn't modify the dictionary, you can simply print the same dictionary you passed in.  I've updated the code so it returns the dict also.

Comment: tbh I think your fisrt version was better, not returning the dictionary because as you said the original will already have the updated keys and you are not "wasting" the return value to return something already existent and the method could be modified in the future to return for example the number of values removed without changes to the already existent calling code.

Comment: Oops!! I dont realize that missing return :( 

thanks for your code Ned!!

Comment: @fsouto - I would use the actual dictionary modified for print (or other) statement and not the return value as when you use `print delete_keys...` you end having a print statement modifying data. Of course this is OK but personaly I avoid do do this because if you don't need anymore to print the dict, you can't only remove the print statement because the dictionary won't be updated so you'll have to remember that and comment it for other programers or for you in a few weeks and I think this is an unecessary potencial source of errors :)

Answer (score 18):

Since the question requested an elegant way, I'll submit my general-purpose solution to wrangling nested structures. First, install the [boltons utility package](http://boltons.readthedocs.org/) with `pip install boltons`, then:

```
from boltons.iterutils import remap

data = {'one': 'remains', 'this': 'goes', 'of': 'course'}
bad_keys = set(['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'keys'])

drop_keys = lambda path, key, value: key not in bad_keys
clean = remap(data, visit=drop_keys)
print(clean)

# Output:
{'one': 'remains'}
```

In short, [the remap utility](http://boltons.readthedocs.org/en/latest/iterutils.html#nested) is a full-featured, yet succinct approach to handling real-world data structures which are often nested, and can even contain cycles and special containers.

[This page](http://sedimental.org/remap.html) has many more examples, including ones working with much larger objects from Github's API.

It's pure-Python, so it works everywhere, and is fully tested in Python 2.7 and 3.3+. Best of all, I wrote it for exactly cases like this, so if you find a case it doesn't handle, you can bug me to fix it [right here](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/issues).

Comment: this should be the correct answer, since the OP asked for an "elegant" way

Answer (score 12):

```
def delete_keys_from_dict(d, to_delete):
    if isinstance(to_delete, str):
        to_delete = [to_delete]
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for single_to_delete in set(to_delete):
            if single_to_delete in d:
                del d[single_to_delete]
        for k, v in d.items():
            delete_keys_from_dict(v, to_delete)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            delete_keys_from_dict(i, to_delete)

d = {'a': 10, 'b': [{'c': 10, 'd': 10, 'a': 10}, {'a': 10}], 'c': 1 }
delete_keys_from_dict(d, ['a', 'c']) # inplace deletion 
print(d)

>>> {'b': [{'d': 10}, {}]}
```

This solution works for `dict` and `list` in a given nested `dict`. The input `to_delete` can be a `list` of `str` to be deleted or a single `str`.

Plese note, that if you remove the only key in a `dict`, you will get an empty `dict`.

Comment: This does what I need, the preferred answer does not as it misses recursion into lists. Question: why the return? It works inplace.

Comment: Excellent question! For consistency and to make explicit that this is an inplace-method, I should remove the return! Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 3):

I think the following is more elegant:

```py
def delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del, lst_keys):
    if not isinstance(dict_del, dict):
        return dict_del
    return {
        key: value
        for key, value in (
            (key, delete_keys_from_dict(value, lst_keys))
            for key, value in dict_del.items()
        )
        if key not in lst_keys
    }
```

Example usage:

```py
test_dict_in = {
    1: {1: {0: 2, 3: 4}},
    0: {2: 3},
    2: {5: {0: 4}, 6: {7: 8}},
}

test_dict_out = {
    1: {1: {3: 4}},
    2: {5: {}, 6: {7: 8}},
}

assert delete_keys_from_dict(test_dict_in, [0]) == test_dict_out
```

Comment: I agree, this would be my approach as well, immutability

Answer (score 2):

Since you already need to loop through every element in the dict, I'd stick with a single loop and just make sure to use a set for looking up the keys to delete

```
def delete_keys_from_dict(dict_del, the_keys):
    """
    Delete the keys present in the lst_keys from the dictionary.
    Loops recursively over nested dictionaries.
    """
    # make sure the_keys is a set to get O(1) lookups
    if type(the_keys) is not set:
        the_keys = set(the_keys)
    for k,v in dict_del.items():
        if k in the_keys:
            del dict_del[k]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            delete_keys_from_dict(v, the_keys)
    return dict_del
```

Comment: @Ned Batchelder : is there a way we can reverse this ? I mean only keep the specific keys and delete rest which are not in list ?

Answer (score 1):

this works with `dict`s containing `Iterable`s (`list`, ...) that may contain `dict`. Python 3. For Python 2 `unicode` should also be excluded from the iteration. Also there may be some iterables that don't work that I'm not aware of. (i.e. will lead to inifinite recursion)

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def deep_omit(d, keys):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in keys:
            d.pop(k, None)
        for v in d.values():
            deep_omit(v, keys)
    elif isinstance(d, Iterable) and not isinstance(d, str):
        for e in d:
            deep_omit(e, keys)

    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody posted an interactive version that could be useful for someone:

```
def delete_key_from_dict(adict, key):
    stack = [adict]
    while stack:
        elem = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(elem, dict):
            if key in elem:
                del elem[key]
            for k in elem:
                stack.append(elem[k])
```

This version is probably what you would push to production. The recursive version is elegant and easy to write but it scales badly (by default Python uses a maximum recursion depth of 1000).

Comment: Can someone help with the upper bound for this algorithm? I guess it gives O(n^2)

Comment: It's effectively a tree traversal where nodes are touched once. [Tree traversals are O(N).](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/tree-traversal-time-complexity#time-complexity-of-the-tree-traversals)

Comment: If there are also embedded lists, tuples or sets with nested dicts, you can add an extra analysis to cover all bases: `if isinstance(elem, (list, tuple, set)): for k in elem: stack.append(k) elif isinstance()...`

Answer (score 0):

If you have **nested** keys as well and based on @John La Rooy's answer here is an elegant solution:

```py
from boltons.iterutils import remap


def sof_solution():
    data = {"user": {"name": "test", "pwd": "******"}, "accounts": ["1", "2"]}
    sensitive = {"user.pwd", "accounts"}

    clean = remap(
        data,
        visit=lambda path, key, value: drop_keys(path, key, value, sensitive)
    )
    print(clean)


def drop_keys(path, key, value, sensitive):
    if len(path) > 0:
        nested_key = f"{'.'.join(path)}.{key}"
        return nested_key not in sensitive
    return key not in sensitive

sof_solution() # prints {'user': {'name': 'test'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the awesome code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27974027/940592) post and add a small statement:

```
    def remove_fields(self, d, list_of_keys_to_remove):
        if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
            return d
        if isinstance(d, list):
            return [v for v in (self.remove_fields(v, list_of_keys_to_remove) for v in d) if v]
        return {k: v for k, v in ((k, self.remove_fields(v, list_of_keys_to_remove)) for k, v in d.items()) if k not in list_of_keys_to_remove}
```

Answer (score -2):

I came here to search for a solution to remove keys from deeply nested Python3 dicts and all solutions seem to be somewhat complex.

Here's a oneliner for removing keys from nested or flat dicts:

```
nested_dict = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "foobar": {},
            "shmoobar": {}
        }
    }
}

>>> {'foo': {'bar': {'foobar': {}, 'shmoobar': {}}}}

nested_dict.get("foo", {}).get("bar", {}).pop("shmoobar", None)

>>> {'foo': {'bar': {'foobar': {}}}}
```

I used .get() to not get KeyError and I also provide empty dict as default value up to the end of the chain. I do pop() for the last element and I provide None as the default there to avoid KeyError.