# How to remove all empty fields in a nested dict?

Tags: python

If I have a dict, which field's values may also be a dict or an array. How can I remove all empty fields in it?

"Empty field" means a field's value is empty array(`[]`), `None`, or empty dict(all sub-fields are empty).

Example:
Input:

```
{
    "fruit": [
        {"apple": 1},
        {"banana": None}
    ],
    "veg": [],
    "result": {
        "apple": 1,
        "banana": None
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "fruit": [
        {"apple": 1}
    ],
    "result": {
        "apple": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use a recursive function that returns a new dictionary:

```
def clean_empty(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {
            k: v 
            for k, v in ((k, clean_empty(v)) for k, v in d.items())
            if v
        }
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return [v for v in map(clean_empty, d) if v]
    return d
```

The `{..}` construct is a dictionary comprehension; it'll only include keys from the original dictionary if `v` is *true*, e.g. not empty. Similarly the `[..]` construct builds a list.

The nested `(.. for ..)` construct is a generator expression that allows the code to compactly filter empty objects *after* recursing.

Another way of constructing such a function is to use the [`@singledispatch` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch); you then write multiple functions, one per object type:

```py
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def clean_empty(obj):
    return obj

@clean_empty.register
def _dicts(d: dict):
    items = ((k, clean_empty(v)) for k, v in d.items())
    return {k: v for k, v in items if v}

@clean_empty.register
def _lists(l: list):
    items = map(clean_empty, l)
    return [v for v in items if v]
```

The above `@singledispatch` version does exactly the same thing as the first function but the `isinstance()` tests are now taken care of by the decorator implementation, based on the type annotations of the registered functions. I also put the nested iterators (the generator expression and `map()` function) into a separate variable to improve readability further.

Note that any values set to *numeric 0* (integer 0, float 0.0) will also be cleared. You can retain numeric 0 values with `if v or v == 0`.

Demo of the first function:

```
>>> sample = {
...     "fruit": [
...         {"apple": 1},
...         {"banana": None}
...     ],
...     "veg": [],
...     "result": {
...         "apple": 1,
...         "banana": None
...     }
... }
>>> def clean_empty(d):
...     if isinstance(d, dict):
...         return {
...             k: v
...             for k, v in ((k, clean_empty(v)) for k, v in d.items())
...             if v
...         }
...     if isinstance(d, list):
...         return [v for v in map(clean_empty, d) if v]
...     return d
... 
>>> clean_empty(sample)
{'fruit': [{'apple': 1}], 'result': {'apple': 1}}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want a full-featured, yet succinct approach to handling real-world data structures which are often nested, and can even contain cycles and other kinds of containers, I recommend looking at [the remap utility from the boltons utility package](http://boltons.readthedocs.org/en/latest/iterutils.html#nested).

After `pip install boltons` or copying [iterutils.py](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/blob/master/boltons/iterutils.py) into your project, just do:

```
from boltons.iterutils import remap

data = {'veg': [], 'fruit': [{'apple': 1}, {'banana': None}], 'result': {'apple': 1, 'banana': None}}

drop_falsey = lambda path, key, value: bool(value)
clean = remap(data, visit=drop_falsey)
print(clean)

# Output:
{'fruit': [{'apple': 1}], 'result': {'apple': 1}}
```

[This page](http://sedimental.org/remap.html) has many more examples, including ones working with much larger objects from Github's API.

It's pure-Python, so it works everywhere, and is fully tested in Python 2.7 and 3.3+. Best of all, I wrote it for exactly cases like this, so if you find a case it doesn't handle, you can bug me to fix it [right here](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/issues).

Answer (score 0):

@mojoken - How about this to overcome the boolean problem

```
def clean_empty(d):
if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
    return d
if isinstance(d, list):
    return [v for v in (clean_empty(v) for v in d) if isinstance(v, bool) or v]
return {k: v for k, v in ((k, clean_empty(v)) for k, v in d.items()) if isinstance(v, bool) or v}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def not_empty(o):
    # you can define what is empty.
    if not (isinstance(o, dict) or isinstance(o, list)):
        return True
    return len(o) > 0


def remove_empty(o):
    # here to choose what container you not need to recursive or to remove
    if not (isinstance(o, dict) or isinstance(o, list)):
        return o
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: remove_empty(v) for k, v in o.items() if not_empty(v)}
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return [remove_empty(v) for v in o if not_empty(v)]
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -2):

```
def remove_empty_fields(data_):
    """
        Recursively remove all empty fields from a nested
        dict structure. Note, a non-empty field could turn
        into an empty one after its children deleted.

        :param data_: A dict or list.
        :return: Data after cleaning.
    """
    if isinstance(data_, dict):
        for key, value in data_.items():

            # Dive into a deeper level.
            if isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                value = remove_empty_fields(value)

            # Delete the field if it's empty.
            if value in ["", None, [], {}]:
                del data_[key]

    elif isinstance(data_, list):
        for index in reversed(range(len(data_))):
            value = data_[index]

            # Dive into a deeper level.
            if isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                value = remove_empty_fields(value)

            # Delete the field if it's empty.
            if value in ["", None, [], {}]:
                data_.pop(index)

    return data_
```

Comment: Does not work mate. It runs into `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`