# Remove all keys excepts those mentioned from a dict python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i have a nested python dictionary where i am trying to remove all keys except those mentioned. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43307143/1045808) where we can remove keys specified, what i am trying to do is reverse of it, i want to remove all keys except those mentioned. So i made a slight change in the function, but i am getting an empty dict.

```
from collections import MutableMapping


def remove_fields(d, list_of_keys_to_remove):
    if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
        return d
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return [v for v in (remove_fields(v, list_of_keys_to_remove) for v in d) if v]
    return {k: v for k, v in ((k, remove_fields(v, list_of_keys_to_remove)) for k, v in d.items()) if
            k in list_of_keys_to_remove}
```

Adding sample input 
**EDIT**: let suppose i want to keep **RENEWAL_TYPE**

```
{
  'G_1': [
    {
      'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '1',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'
    },
    {
      'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '2',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'
    },
    {
      'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '3',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'DO_NOT_RENEW'
    },
    {
     'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '4',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the intersection between the set of keys in the dict and the set of values in the list. i.e. all keys that exist in both sets.

Try this:

```
from collections import MutableMapping


d = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4 }
list_of_keys_to_keep = ['B', 'C', 'F']

def remove_fields(d, list_of_keys_to_keep):
    return {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key in list_of_keys_to_keep}

print(remove_fields(d, list_of_keys_to_keep)) # -> {'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Edit: Updated name of list_of_keys_to_remove to list_of_keys_to_keep since this seems to be what it actually represents.

Edit2: Updated after Askers update. The following works for the sample provided:

from collections import MutableMapping

```
d = {
  'G_1': [
    {
      'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '1',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'
    },
    {
      'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '2',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'
    },
    {
      'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '3',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'DO_NOT_RENEW'
    },
    {
     'ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID': '4',
      'PAYMENT_TERM_ID': '4',
      'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'
    }
  ]
}
list_of_keys_to_keep = ['RENEWAL_TYPE']

def filter_dict(di, keys):
    if not isinstance(di, (dict, list)):
        return di
    if isinstance(di, list):
        return [filter_dict(value, keys) for value in di]
    return {key: filter_dict(value, keys) for key, value in di.items() if key in keys or isinstance(value, (dict, list))}

print(filter_dict(d, list_of_keys_to_keep))
```

Output:

```
{'G_1': [{'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'}, {'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'}, {'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'DO_NOT_RENEW'}, {'RENEWAL_TYPE': 'RENEW'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```py
dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
keys_to_preserve = ["e", "b", "c"]

dict_final={k: v for k,v in dict.items() if k in keys_to_preserve}
```

Comment: This would fail for nested dictionaries.

Comment: hm, could you share sample input then ?

Comment: Updated question, please check

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_fields(d, keys_to_preserve):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return [remove_fields(v, keys_to_preserve) for v in d]
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        return dict([(k, remove_fields(v, keys_to_preserve)) for k, v in d.items() if k in keys_to_preserve])
    else:
        return d
```