# Ignore specific keys in a dictionary using robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

How can I ignore specific keys in a dictionary using robot framework script? The dictionary is a nested dictionary.I tried with the below code but it removes the keys at the first level only. Any help is appreciated.

```
*** Variables ***
&{type}    mobile=android    mobileV2=windows
&{DICTIONARY}     interface=ethernet    interfaceId=default    favorite=false    mobile=android    mobileV2=windows    type=&{type}

*** Test Cases ***
Filter Dictionary Values
    Log    \nDictionaty values... : ${DICTIONARY}  console=${True}
    ${d1_filtered} =      Evaluate    {k:v for k,v in ${DICTIONARY}.items() if k not in ('mobile','mobileV2')}
    Log    \nDictionaty filtered values... : ${d1_filtered}  console=${True}
```

The resulting output log is given below.

Dictionaty filtered values... : {'interface': 'ethernet', 'interfaceId': 'default', 'favorite': 'false', 'type': {'mobile': 'android', 'mobileV2': 'windows'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your library and import it [here.](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module)
Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405715/elegant-way-to-remove-fields-from-nested-dictionaries) the library can look something like this.

```
class MyLibrary:
    def deleteKeys(self, dict_del, lst_keys: list):
        for k in lst_keys:
            try:
                del dict_del[k]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        for v in dict_del.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                self.deleteKeys(v, lst_keys)


        return dict_del


if __name__=="__main__":
    mydict= {'interface': 'ethernet', 'interfaceId': 'default', 'favorite': 'false', 'mobile': 'android', 'mobileV2': 'windows', 'type': {'mobile': 'android', 'mobileV2': 'windows'}}
    bad_keys = ['mobile','mobileV2']
    lib = MyLibrary()
    test = lib.deleteKeys(mydict, bad_keys)
    print(test)
```

Here is the robot file:

```
***Settings***
Library     ./MyLibrary.py
*** Variables ***
&{type}    mobile=android    mobileV2=windows
&{DICTIONARY}     interface=ethernet    interfaceId=default    favorite=false    mobile=android    mobileV2=windows    type=&{type}
@{remove_list}    mobile    mobileV2

*** Test Cases ***
Filter Dictionary Values
    Log    \nDictionaty values... : ${DICTIONARY}
    ${d1_filtered}=    MyLibrary.deleteKeys    ${DICTIONARY}    ${remove_list}
    Log    \nDictionaty filtered values... : ${d1_filtered}
```