# How to update only some fields in a document with Pymongo

Tags: pymongo

suppose we have the following document:

```
{ '_id': 1, 'Name': 'Document1', 'Data': { 'Color': 'Green', 'Size': 5 } }
```

And we want to update the document using Pymongo using a dict as source.
For instance, let's suppose that this is the dict we want to use to update the document:

```
dict1 = { 'Name': 'Document1', 'Data': { 'Size': 5 } }
```

If we know for sure which are the fields contained in `dict1` we could use:

```
collection.update_one( { 'Name': dict1['Name'] }, { '$set': { 'Data.Size': dict1['Data']['Size'] } })
```

In the general case in which we don't know what is inside the `['Data']` field of `dict1`, the following approach:

```
collection.update_one( { 'Name': dict1['Name'] }, { '$set': { 'Data': dict1['Data'] } })
```

Will potentially delete any fields which were present in the document but are not in dict1 (in our example, `'Color'`).

Is it possible to tell Pymongo that we want to update a field (which is containing many fields) but only inserting/updating fields in the source dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the aggregation flavour of [`$set`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe) (aka `$addFields`) to achieve this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
collection = db.mycollection

collection.insert_one({'_id': 1, 'Name': 'Document1', 'Data': {'Color': 'Green', 'Size': 5}})
dict1 = {'Name': 'Document1', 'Data': {'Size': 6, 'Fitting': 'Wide'}}

collection.update_many({'Name': dict1.get('Name')}, [{'$addFields': {'Data': dict1.get('Data')}}])

print(collection.find_one())
```

prints:

```
{'_id': 1, 'Name': 'Document1', 'Data': {'Color': 'Green', 'Size': 6, 'Fitting': 'Wide'}}
```

Comment: This is not working if dict1 contains some values with void dicts inside (e.g. dict1 = {'Name': 'Document1', 'Data': {}}). To avoid errors, I've implemented a cleaning stage in order to remove values = {} following the approach mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405715/elegant-way-to-remove-fields-from-nested-dictionaries